# Is there a better word for "whistle-blower"?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there any better word than whistle-blower to refer to those who reveal classified information to the public? In my opinion, it's a cheap way to refer to them, given the courage shown by the individual who has sometimes even put their life on the line in case of autocratic regimes.

Comment: Nearly all the synonyms given by [WordHippo](https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/another-word-for/whistle-blower.html) are negative, even pejorative. Whistle-blower is relatively neutral.

Comment: What exact meaning do you want? Whistle-blower is a good word, but maybe you mean something more general like a dissident or freedom-fighter or democracy-campaigner. Voting down anyway because you haven't done any research and don't explain what you want.

Answer (score 5):

I think "whistleblower" generally is understood as indicating a great deal of courage. However, it is usually used to describe people revealing misconduct in a corporation or government agency.

If you want to describe someone standing up to an authoritarian regime, you could use the word **dissident.** [MacMillan defines it as:](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/dissident)

> someone who disagrees publicly with a government, especially in a country where this is not allowed